# Does gsutil support sigv4 for aws s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, gsutil

We are trying to use gsutil to sync our buckets in s3 to GCS from an AWS EMR instance.

The EMR instance already has a /etc/boto.cfg file with:

[s3]

use-sigv4 = True

Doing a 'gsutil ls s3://' gives:

Failure: BotoClientError: When using SigV4, you must specify a 'host' parameter..

Removing /etc/boto.cfg or removing the corresponding entry 'use-sigv4' fixes this issue.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Gsutil does not currently support Signature Version 4.</strike>

**Edit 2:**

Gsutil 4.28 has been released and this now works via the instructions below.

**Edit:**

I've added a change to the Boto library [in this commit](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/221699bc561cc867f62f279d2ce9ed154b1b4369) to allow using sigv4 through Boto settings. Gsutil *should* be able to pull in this new version of Boto whenever our next release (v4.28) comes out, allowing you to utilize sigv4 for auth'ing against S3 via adding these two Boto settings:

```
[s3]
use-sigv4 = True
host = s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com  # Or whatever region is correct.
```

That being said, at this time I unfortunately don't have an ETA on when we can expect to release gsutil 4.28.